# Android popup layout with radio buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some problems creating a popup layout with a title `TextView`, 2 `ImageViews`, 2 `RadioButtons`, 2 `TextViews` to describe the images and a `Button` to dismiss the popup. here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/img1"
            android:text="Choose Your Preference:"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/first">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pre"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/optionone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/img2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Shrink image and leave borders white."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pre"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/optiontwo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Change image brightness."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Dismiss"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image: description]

However, I have two problems with it:

**1.** I am using `android:layout_above:""` inside a `LinearLayout`, but it works only this way and not inside a `RelativeLayout`, and also if I will switch to a `RelativeLayout` I will not be able to use `android:layout_weight=""`

**2.** I can't get `RadioButton` "first" to the left of `ImageView` "img1" and `RadioButton` "second" to the left of `ImageView` "img2".

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RadioButton` class extends `TextView`. So instead of using a separate `ImageView` for each of your option images, you could use the `android:drawable` attributes of the `RadioButton` to display the image where you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose Your Preference:"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/first">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shrink image and leave borders white."
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/optionone" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change image brightness."
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/optiontwo" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Dismiss" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And what about using android:layout_above="" inside a LinearLayout?

Comment: You are correct.
In attempting to assist you I, made an error when copying, pasting and correcting your original xml layout, by not deleting the `layout_above=` line.
I am so sorry. Please forgive me. I have removed the offending line of *YOUR* code

Comment: That's fine, I just thought you had a mistake, sorry bro :(